# How can I pass a function as an optional variable to call_user_func in PHP

Tags: php, php-5.2

So I'd like to use the `call_user_func` to pass data to an optional parameter of a function.

Here's the example of a code, the optional parameter `$data` represents a functional called `data` that was declared in another file. I just want it to be called by using `call_user_func` that will set the parameter with the function's name and call it within the createtable function, but doesn't seem to work.

I got the example from the PHP Manual, but `createTable` contains many parameters. How can I make `call_user_func` only assign the string `data` to the optional parameter `$data` set to `NULL` as default?

```
function createTable($database, $table, $patch,$data = NULL)
{

    echo "INFO: Adding '$table'in database '$database'.\n";
    $sql = "SHOW TABLES FROM $database WHERE Tables_in_$database='$table';";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $result_count = mysql_num_rows($result);

    if ( $result_count != 1 ) {
          echo "ERROR: Can not find table '$table' in database '$database'.\n";
          $result = mysql_query($patch);
          if ( false === $result ) {
                echo "ERROR: Adding Table '$table' in database '$database' ... Failed\n";
                return false;
            }
          else {
          echo "INFO: Adding Table '$table'in database '$database' ... Success\n";
             // using the optional parameter here 
              $data();
          return true;
               }

    } else {

        if ( $result_count == 1 ) {
            echo "ERROR: Table '$table'already in database '$database'.\n";
            return false;
        }

    }
}

// Now I'm passing value to the optional parameter $ data that is NULL as default.

call_user_func('createTable', "data");
```

Comment: using PHP Version 5.2.11

Comment: Then why have you tagged your question with `php-5.3` & `php-5.4`?

Comment: TO BETTER my chances of my question to be seen by the whole PHP community.

Comment: Then why haven't you also tagged it with `Java`, `C#`, `Ruby`, `Python` & `Perl`? That would insure that *even more* people will see it.

Comment: In all seriousness though, you should only tag your question with relative tags. I edited your tags.

Comment: `createTable` takes 3 (or 4) parameters.  `call_user_func` needs to pass the *correct* number of params when calling the function.

Comment: Those are different languages , I wanted the PHP people to see it . Why are you looking for arguments ?  What I did made sense , I tagged the PHP people because they are assumed to know PHP . Java and C-sharp , I just can't guess or assume they would help .

Comment: @RocketHazmat, I only wanna pass"data" to the fourth optional parameter set as NULL , so how would I do it in call_user_func for the other parameters that won't need a value ?

Comment: @JBa: You can't do that.  What would the 1st 3 parameters be set to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must pass value like this

```
call_user_func('createTable', $database, $table, $patch,$data);
```

or this for call from class

```
call_user_func(array(&$objectName->{$anotherObject},$functionName), $arg1, $arg2, $arg2);
```

or you can use this can get arg as array

```
call_user_func_array("createTable", array("one", "two"));
```

or this for call from class can get arg as array

```
call_user_func_array(array($foo, "bar"), array("three", "four"));
```

or This can help you too it not need to pass all args

```
 function __named($method, array $args = array()) 
{ 

$reflection = new ReflectionFunction( $method); 

$pass = array(); 
foreach($reflection->getParameters() as $param) 
{ 
  /* @var $param ReflectionParameter */ 
  if(isset($args[$param->getName()])) 
  { 
    $pass[] = $args[$param->getName()]; 
  } 
  else 
  { 
    try{
       $pass[] = $param->getDefaultValue();
    }catch(Exception $e){
       $pass[] = NULL; 
    }
  } 
} 

  return $reflection->invokeArgs( $pass); 
 }
```

I hope It Work

sample:

```
__named('createTable', array('data' => 'value'));
```

and it is for use in class

```
public function __named($method, array $args = array()) 
{ 

   $reflection = new ReflectionMethod($this, $method); 

   $pass = array(); 
   foreach($reflection->getParameters() as $param) 
   { 
      /* @var $param ReflectionParameter */ 
      if(isset($args[$param->getName()])) 
      { 
         $pass[] = $args[$param->getName()]; 
      } 
      else 
      { 
     try{
           $pass[] = $param->getDefaultValue();
         }catch(Exception $e){
            $pass[] = NULL; 
         }
      } 
   } 

   return $reflection->invokeArgs($this,$pass); 
}
```

if you Don't set any value  __named Put Null instead of Unset Value

Comment: What if I don't want to passe any value to $database, $table and $patch but only $data .. How would I format call_user_func ?

Comment: @JBaL If you don't pass $database, $table, and $patch what do you expect them to be set to?

Answer (score 1):

Even with `call_user_func` you have to pass all the parameters.

Anyway, `call_user_func` is intended for use when the name of the function isn't necessarily known up front. For instance, you might have several functions and a variable, and the variable contains the name of the function to call.

Personally I think it's on par with `eval` and variable variables: A horrible idea. After all, if you have `$foo = "function_name";` then you can call `$foo()` and it will call `function_name`.

Anyway, back to the point, just call it as a normal function and give it the parameters it needs. Pass `null` if you have to.

Comment: so how would I make it so "data" only gets assigned to the last optional parameter in createTable ???

Comment: Give it values for the required parameters, then add one more parameter for the optional one.

Comment: I don't think you understood what I meant ... I only wanna pass data to the last optional parameter ... what should I fill in for the other parameters that need data from the call_user_func ??

Comment: The other parameters are REQUIRED. You cannot call the function without them.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you just want to pass the last param, and not worry about the 1st three.  I don't think `call_user_func` is the right tool here at all.

Why not just make a function that calls your function?

```
function call_createTable($data){
    $database = '...';
    $table = '...';
    $patch = '...';

    return createTable($database, $table, $patch, $data);
}
```

Then just simply call it like this: `call_createTable("data");`.